# Display a tool tip on current document

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I am developing a code editor like VS.  I want to display a tool tip window when mouse cursor lands on a text. The `ToolTip.Show()` method asks for a IWin32Window parameter...

Please tell me how to display the tool tip in the current document just as Visual Studio Intellisense works.

Comment: More information is needed here.  What control are you using to display your text?  Is this a custom control?  Why can't you detect the mouse position and change the tooltiptext accordingly?

Comment: i am developing an addin....so irrespective of what the document is i need tooltip to be displayed..can you please tell me how to deal with Win32Window parameter i tried this                                      ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
tt.Show(TextSelection.Text,(IWin32Window)_applicationObject.ActiveWindow);    but this is not working ...thanx brad

Answer (score 0):

[`ToolTip.Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67fds2ee.aspx) Method (String, IWin32Window)

The second argument is the control for which the tool tip is to be shown.

```
toolTip1.Show("Test 123", button1, Int32.MaxValue);
```

Visual Studio tracks the word underneath the mouse and displays tooltips/intellisense accordingly. One way for you to do the same could be to:

1. Track the [mouse movements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
2. Get the [text under](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb-interop/MouseHunter.aspx) mouse
3. [Show tooltip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

**The `ToolTip.Show` method also has other more appropriate overloads, like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c85ff5s9.aspx).**

You can pass the edit control (that is, your text box) that you want to be associated with the tooltip as the `IWin32Window` parameter.

Then, you can specify the current coordinates of the mouse cursor as the `X` and `Y` arguments:

- If you're trying to show this tooltip in one of the mouse event handlers (like [`MouseMove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx)), the current coordinates of the mouse cursor are passed in as part of the [`MouseEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx)—just use the `e.X` and `e.Y` properties.
- Otherwise, you'll need to use the [`Control.MousePosition` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition.aspx) to get its current location, which will return a `Point` representing its current location relative to screen coordinates. [Another one of the overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44atyhsa.aspx) to the `ToolTip.Show` method accepts a `Point` parameter that you can use here instead of separate X and Y coordinates